# Midrash Rabbah - Edition

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, midrash

The accuracy and reliability of various editions of Midrashim, especially Midrash Rabbah, is not great. I have the few available volumes by Mechon Schecter, who have been putting out critical editions of Midrashim. However, most of the Midrash Rabbah volumes have not been released. Where can one buy an accurate and reliable edition of Midrash Rabbah?

Comment: Artscroll have got a great set unless you're looking purely for Hebrew text?

Comment: @Dov what makes it great? Is it accuracy and reliability of the base text?

Comment: Good clear text, translation and annotations

Comment: @Dov what makes the text "good"? The rest is not what he asked about

Comment: Take a look for yourself - https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422617465.html - there are sample pages. The text is very crisp.

Comment: @Dov Crisp doesn't seem relevant... I feel like you're missing the point of the question

Comment: I am not sure there is an accurate version of Medrash Rabbah available.

Comment: I would recommend getting an edition that acknowledges questions in the text and gives several possibilities. I don't think there is any one person alive I would trust to definitively determine the final version of the text.

Answer (score 3):

Midrash Rabbah is a collection of disparate texts, so you shouldn't expect to find a single good all-encompassing edition. As far as I know, besides the [Schechter Institutes](https://schechter.edu/the-midrash-project/) editions you already mentioned, here are some of the critical editions available:

- Bereishit Rabbah: [ed. Theodore–Albeck](https://tablet.otzar.org/he/book/book.php?book=16944)
- Shemot Rabbah: [ed. Shinan](https://brill.com/view/journals/jsj/16/2/article-p288_22.xml?language=en) (on chapters 1–14)
- Vayikra Rabbah: [ed. Margaliot](http://www.schocken-jts.org.il/english/bookstore/prodView.asp?idproduct=153) (2 volumes), [ed. Milikowsky–Schlüter](https://www2.biu.ac.il/JS/midrash/VR/editionData.htm) (online)
- Devarim Rabbah: [ed. Lieberman](https://tablet.otzar.org/he/book/book.php?book=177246)

With the Shechter Institutes having already published Esther, Kohelet, and planning to publish Bemidbar, Ruth, Eikhah, and Shir HaShirim, you've essentially got your Midrash Rabbah covered. (I don't know of prior critical editions of those, nor of a critical edition of the rest of Shemot Rabbah).

Comment: There are also critical editions of other midrashim by Horowitz–Rabin, Finkelstein, Kensky, Mandelbaum, Visotzky, Kahana...

Comment: I should have been more specific. I am only looking for print editions, not digital ones. The print editions provided above are very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to get a new copy of the Albeck editions?

Comment: Where can critical editions of other Midrashim be purchased in hard copy?

Comment: Does anyone know if the Oz VeHadar editions are based on manuscript work?

Comment: It's out of print, but you can look on AbeBooks to find reprints (do your homework as to which edition is being reprinted, first).

Comment: What other midrashim are you looking for?